# IE 11 Nest(firebase) authentication/websocket error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firebase, internet-explorer-11, nest-api

I am using the javascript firebase library to connect to the nest api. It works great in Chrome and FireFox. But in internet explorer (I'm using IE11) I get an script/websocket error.

```
SCRIPT12008: WebSocket Error: Incorrect HTTP response. Status code 401, Unauthorized
```

I have no problems connecting to a normal firebase server/URL.

I need IE to run cause other people use it.

Any ideas??

this is the code i use to connect to the nest api

```
var dataRef = new Firebase('wss://developer-api.nest.com/');
dataRef.authWithCustomToken("{{user.token}}", function(error, authData) {
console.log("{{user.token}}");
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Login Succeeded!", authData);
  }
});`
```

Comment: Unless you want to share some code (so that people here can see if you could do things differently), this reads like a bug report for support@firebase.com.

Comment: added the code I use

Comment: Can't provide a solution I'm afraid, but I can confirm that I get the same results. Never bothered checking in IE before!

Comment: That is to bad. I don't know where the issue commes from. I think I need to contact firebase support and nest-api support. Maybe one of them made a mistake. But they really need to have or make a fix for it.

Comment: I have send a email to the firebase support. the should react today or tomorow. I have not send an email to the nest api support, because I could not find there email. But they schould be very active at stackoverflow. I hope the read this and try to fix it. Hoping for a fast respons

Comment: support@firebase.com says that it is an issue at the side of the Nest team.